# PowerShell - Creating Zip file leaves zero-byte files

Tags: tomcat, powershell, byte, 7zip, zero

When running the following on our Windows 2003/2008 with folder compression turned on/off, I am seeing zero-byte files left-over..  Something is odd..

Logs are Apache Tomcat Logs.  They end a .0 or 1 from what appears to be the zero-byte file that is leftover.

**Please be careful not to use this function - corrected solution is in my answer below!!**

```
function create7zip([String] $aZip, [String] $aDir, $DTNew){
If  ((Get-Item "$aDir").length -eq 0) {
    Remove-Item -Force $aDir
} else {
    [string]$pathToZipExe = "D:\WORK\SCRIPTS\7za.exe";
    [Array]$arguments = "a", "-tzip", "$aZip", "$aDir", "-r";
    & $pathToZipExe $arguments;
    Start-Sleep -s 3
    if ($DTNew) {
        (dir $aZip).lastwritetime = $DTNew
    }
    Remove-Item -Force $aDir
}
```

}

And is "called" by:

```
    # 3 ARCHIVE LOGS
$server = gc env:computername
$date = Get-Date -f yyyy-MM-dd
$ZipFolder = "D:\logs\ArchiveTemp\"
$ZipFolder2 = "D:\logs\ArchiveTemp\AudForen\"
$ZipFolder3 = "D:\logs\ArchiveTemp\Tomcat\"
$company = "COMPANY"
$DataCenter = "ANYTOWN"
# LOAD IN THE FUNCTION TO DETECT TOMCAT INFO
$ScriptDir = Split-Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path
. ( Join-Path $ScriptDir tomcat.ps1 )
. ( Join-Path $ScriptDir sftp.ps1 )
. ( Join-Path $ScriptDir zip.ps1 )
. ( Join-Path $ScriptDir testlock.ps1 )
$returnvalue = TomcatLog
$LogLocation = $returnvalue[2]  # LogDir
if (Test-Path -Path $LogLocation)
{
    $files = Get-ChildItem $LogLocation
    foreach ($file in $files)
    {
        $FLName = $file.Name
        $FLPath = $file.FullName
        $CharacterCount = [regex]::matches($FLName, "-").count
        if ($CharacterCount -gt 1)
        {
            $YearVar = $FLName.Split("-")[0]
            $YearVar = $YearVar.Substring($YearVar.Length-4, 4)
            $MonthVar = $FLName.Split("-")[1]
            $DayVar = $FLName.Split("-")[2]
            $DateVar = $YearVar + "-" + $MonthVar + "-" + $DayVar
            $DateVar = $DateVar.Substring(0, 10)
            $DateAdNm = Get-Date (Get-Date $DateVar).AddDays(1) -format yyyyMMdd
            $DateAd = Get-Date (Get-Date $DateVar).AddDays(1) -format yyyy-MM-dd
            if (!($DateVar -eq $date))
            {
                if ($FLName -match 'audit|forensic')
                {
                    If (!(TestFileLock $FLPath -eq -true))
                    {
                    $AuditLogZip = $ZipFolder2 + "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}_{1}_{2}@{3}.zip" -f $DateAdNm, $company, $server, $DataCenter
                    #compress $AuditLogZip $FLPath $DateAd
                    create7zip $AuditLogZip $FLPath $DateAd
                    SFTP $AuditLogZip
                    }
                }
                elseif ($CharacterCount -gt 2)
                {
                    $HourVar = $FLName.Split("-")[3]
                    if ($HourVar -gt 11)
                    {
                        $HourVar = $HourVar - 12
                        $HourVar = $HourVar.ToString("00")
                    }
                    if ($HourVar -gt 0)
                    {
                    $Var = $MonthVar + "-" + $DayVar + "-" + $YearVar +"-"+$HourVar+"-00-00-compressed.zip"
                    }
                    If (!(TestFileLock $FLPath -eq -true))
                    {
                    #$HourlyZip = $ZipFolder + "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}-{1}{2}-00-00-compressed.zip" -f $server, ( Get-Date($DateVar) -format yyyy-MM-dd )
                    #compress $HourlyZip $FLPath ( Get-Date($DateVar) -format yyyy-MM-dd )
                    #Write-host $HourlyZip $FLPath ( Get-Date($DateVar) -format yyyy-MM-dd )
                    $HourlyZip = $ZipFolder + "{0}-{1}" -f $server, $Var
                    #compress $HourlyZip $FLPath ( Get-Date($DateVar) -format yyyy-MM-dd )
                    create7zip $HourlyZip $FLPath ( Get-Date($DateVar) -format yyyy-MM-dd )
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    If (!(TestFileLock $FLPath -eq -true))
                    {
                    $TomCatZip = $ZipFolder3 + "{0}-Tomcat-{1:yyyy-MM-dd}-compressed.zip" -f $server, ( Get-Date($DateVar) -format yyyy-MM-dd )
                    #compress $TomCatZip $FLPath ( Get-Date($DateVar) -format yyyy-MM-dd )
                    #Write-host $TomCatZip $FLPath ( Get-Date($DateVar) -format yyyy-MM-dd )
                    create7zip $TomCatZip $FLPath ( Get-Date($DateVar) -format yyyy-MM-dd )
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
        $CurrentDate = Get-Date
        $CurrentDate = $CurrentDate.AddHours(-($CurrentDate.Hour))
        $CurrentDate = $CurrentDate.AddMinutes(-($CurrentDate.Minute))
        $fileaffected = Get-ChildItem $FLPath |  select LastWriteTime
        If ($fileaffected.LastWriteTime -lt $CurrentDate) {
        #write-host "we are going to move the file $FLPath $fileaffected.LastWriteTime"
            If (!(TestFileLock $FLPath -eq -true))
            {
            $TomCatZip = $ZipFolder3 + "{0}-Tomcat-{1:yyyy-MM-dd}-compressed.zip" -f $server, ( Get-Date($DateVar) -format yyyy-MM-dd )
            #compress $TomCatZip $FLPath ( Get-Date($DateVar) -format yyyy-MM-dd )
            create7zip $TomCatZip $FLPath ( Get-Date($DateVar) -format yyyy-MM-dd )
            Write-host $TomCatZip $FLPath ( Get-Date($DateVar) -format yyyy-MM-dd )
            }
        #} else {
        #write-host "we are going to leave the file $FLPath $fileaffected.LastWriteTime"
        }
        #If ($file.LastWriteTime -lt $DatetoMove) {
        #   $TomCatZip = $ZipFolder3 + "{0}-Tomcat-{1:yyyy-MM-dd}-compressed.zip" -f $server, ( Get-Date($DateVar) -format yyyy-MM-dd )
        #   compress $TomCatZip $FLPath ( Get-Date($DateVar) -format yyyy-MM-dd )
        #   }
        }
    }
}
```

Have tried a couple versions of 7-Zip..
D:\WORK\Scripts>7z

7-Zip 9.22 beta  Copyright (c) 1999-2011 Igor Pavlov  2011-04-18

as well as:
D:\WORK\Scripts>7za

7-Zip (A) 9.20  Copyright (c) 1999-2010 Igor Pavlov  2010-11-18

Note - We are running Tomcat and not IIS (no ISAPI Redirect) - hence this is not relevant: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/817442 but we do have folder compression turned on.

Turned folder compression off and we still see the zero-byte files.

It was suspect that VirusScan was getting in the way, but I can run similar code in VBS and this works perfectly.

The main driver for me to get away from VBS is that corporate has placed a mandate on code-signing vbs and PowerShell is excluded from that.

Thanks,

Kent

Comment: How are you running this?

Comment: Windows Task Scheduler:  PowerShell -file "D:\Work\ps\zip_up_files.ps1"

Comment: Issue link: https://github.com/PowerShell/Microsoft.PowerShell.Archive/issues/27

Answer (score 0):

As silly as this sounds, I have solved my own question.  This was bugging me that it was working fine in VBS, but not PowerShell?  Went back and re-looked at the code again.

We have to remember that PowerShell is a pipelining language..

We need to move things around in the function a bit..

Note: We now remove the file we just after added to the Zip file before re-date stamping the zip file.
Also adjusted some of the switches for 7-zip..

```
function create7zip([String] $aZip, [String] $aDir, $DTNew){ If  ((Get-Item "$aDir").length -eq 0) {
Remove-Item -Force $aDir } else {
[string]$pathToZipExe = "D:\WORK\SCRIPTS\7za.exe";
[Array]$arguments = "-tzip", "-y", "a", "$aZip", "$aDir";
& $pathToZipExe $arguments;
Remove-Item -Force $aDir }   if ($DTNew) {
    (dir $aZip).lastwritetime = $DTNew } }
```

And it now works great.

Thanks,

Kent